# Dataverse Integration toolkit - Write back Error from Dataverse to Azure FHIR Service

Tags: azure, microsoft-dynamics, hl7-fhir, dataverse, fhir-server-for-azure

We have configured the data integration toolkit in Dynamics 365 and enabled the Dataverse Healthcare APIs Writeback also enabled the entity mapping and writeback on Contact<->Patient but when I update a contact it gives us, this below error in the integration logs

*The data cannot be sent to the Azrue FHIR Server,Azure FHIR Sync Enabled flag being set to false.This attribute needs to be set to true before changes to the contacts are pushed back to FHIR*

but as we know the Azure Fhir sync agent has been deprecated. Does anyone knw how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a column named - **Azure FHIR Sync Enabled**, in Contact table in Dataverse. You need to set that to **Yes**(true) for the Patient record you are trying to write-back. You can also edit that column and set its default value to **Yes**, so that you don't have to enable it for each and every Patient(Contact) record.